# How can i validate file upload using Respect\Validation library?

Tags: php, file, upload, slim, respect-validation

I use [Slim 3 Framework](https://www.slimframework.com/) on my project, and i have a form with 3 inputs : `'file', 'name', 'firstname'`.

Assuming that `$request` has the data inputs of my form, to get the uploaded file, i use this code

```
$files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    if (empty($files['file'])) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid image');
    }
$newfile = $files['file'];
```

Then, to validate my input forms, i use the [Respect\Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) Library

```
$validation = $this->validator->validate($request, [
        'file' => v::file()->mimetype('application/pdf'),
        'name' => v::stringType()->notEmpty()->length(2, 50)->alpha(),
        'firstname' => v::stringType()->notEmpty()->length(2, 50)->alpha()
]);


if($validation->failed() {
     //...
}
```

The fact is the file validation always fails :

```
var_dump($request->getParam('file')); //return NULL
var_dump($newfile); //return the following
```

`$newfile` content

```
object(Slim\Http\UploadedFile)#59 (8) { 
    ["file"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php409Uje" 
    ["name":protected]=> string(47) "Myfile.pdf" 
    ["type":protected]=> string(15) "application/pdf" 
    ["size":protected]=> int(1404476) ["error":protected]=> int(0) 
    ["sapi":protected]=> bool(true) ["stream":protected]=> NULL 
    ["moved":protected]=> bool(false) 
}
```

So now I'm stuck. I really can't figure out how can i tell the validator to validate `$newfile MIMETYPE` for the 'file' input.

Comment: according to the documentation (https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/1.1/docs/Mimetype.md), this should work: `'file' => v::mimetype('application/pdf')`

Comment: Yes of course, I checked the docs before posting, and I tried that, but as I mentionned in my post, `file` returns NULL since i need -i think- to get files with getUploadedFiles(), so the validation will always fail because NULL is not `application/pdf` type

Comment: can you show me what is `$this->validator`? or the code, where you intialize it in the `$container`?

Comment: `$container['validator'] = function ($container) {
    return new App\Validation\Validator;
};`

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, eveything is working well, i'm just stuck on that file validation

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the mimetype using the `file` attribute of [`UploadedFile` class](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/UploadedFile.php).

For example:

```
$uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
$uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['file'];

$validationResult = v::file()->mimetype('application/pdf')->validate($uploadedFile->file);
if($validationResult){
    echo "Validation ok";
} else {
    echo "Validation error";
}
```

Files and other parameters are handled in different ways so you can't access files using the classic `getParam($name)` method.
The bad news about it is that you can't use a single validation step, but you have to use one for all the `POST` parameters and another one for the files. This means in your specific case that you have to do something like this:

```
$validation = $this->validator->validate($request, [
        'file' => v::file()->mimetype('application/pdf'),
        'name' => v::stringType()->notEmpty()->length(2, 50)->alpha(),
        'firstname' => v::stringType()->notEmpty()->length(2, 50)->alpha()
]);

$uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();

if (empty($uploadedFiles['file'])) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid image');
}

$uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['file'];

$fileValidationResult = v::file()->mimetype('application/pdf')->validate($uploadedFile->file);

if($validation->failed() || !$fileValidationResult) {
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but you can try

```
v::objectType()->attribute('file', v::oneOf(
    v::mimetype('application/pdf'),
    v::mimetype('image/png')
))->validate($uploadedFile);
```

Where $uploadedFile is an instance of \Slim\Http\UploadedFile

You can as many validators as you want in "oneOf"